# PHP - How to skip first row when importing csv file?

Tags: php

I'm want to skip the first row of my csv file for the use of header purposes.
Using a while loop, how can I make it skip the first row? Thank you in advanced guys.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db($con, 'test');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file,"r");
        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,2000,",")) !==false)
        {

            $KeyAccount = $fileop[0];
            $BatchNumber= $fileop[1];
            $Product = $fileop[2];
            $Quantity = $fileop[3];
            $PO = $fileop[4];
            $DateRequested = $fileop[5];
            $DateDelivered = $fileop[6];
            $Status = $fileop[7];
            $Serial = $fileop[8];
            $Voucher = $fileop[9];
            $DateExpiry = $fileop[10];
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO orders (KeyAccount,BatchNumber,Product,Quantity,PO,DateRequested,DateDelivered,Status,Serial,Voucher,DateExpiry) VALUES ('$KeyAccount','$BatchNumber','$Product','$Quantity','$PO','$DateRequested','$DateDelivered','$Status','$Serial','$Voucher','$DateExpiry')");
        }
        if($sql)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Successfully Inserted.")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else{

            echo "error";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you list the first several lines of the data file?

Answer (score 0):

Just add one "junk" call:

```
$junk = fgetcsv($handle,2000,",");
```

before the while loop.

Comment: hi thank you for the reply! I added a junk call before the while loop, it did ignored the first row of my csv. But it somehow gave me 2 extra datas that are blank inside my database. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @JohnDale Maybe the CSV file has some blank lines.

Comment: @JohnDale Check `count($fileop)` to make sure it has the correct number of fields, and skip invalid lines.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and wrapped the contents of the while () statement inside of an if () statement.

I added a flag (i.e., $num) to track if the first iteration was being processed.
The if () checks to see if $num equals 0 and if it does, it increments it.
Your while () code will not get processed for that iteration.
The next iteration, the $num flag will not equal 0 and process the contents of the while () statement.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db($con, 'test');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    $num = 0;
    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,2000,",")) !==false){
        if($num == 0){
            $num++;
        } 
        else{
            $KeyAccount = $fileop[0];
            $BatchNumber= $fileop[1];
            $Product = $fileop[2];
            $Quantity = $fileop[3];
            $PO = $fileop[4];
            $DateRequested = $fileop[5];
            $DateDelivered = $fileop[6];
            $Status = $fileop[7];
            $Serial = $fileop[8];
            $Voucher = $fileop[9];
            $DateExpiry = $fileop[10];
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO orders (KeyAccount,BatchNumber,Product,Quantity,PO,DateRequested,DateDelivered,Status,Serial,Voucher,DateExpiry) VALUES ('$KeyAccount','$BatchNumber','$Product','$Quantity','$PO','$DateRequested','$DateDelivered','$Status','$Serial','$Voucher','$DateExpiry')");
        }
    }
    if($sql){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Successfully Inserted.")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution to parsing CSV file. The only catch is that the CSV data is simple comma separated values, ie: Comma is purely separator and not part of the column data (eg: cannot work with `one,two,"three,four",five`), and the data does not contain line breaks.

First, sample data:

> header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8,header9,header10,header11
>   KeyAccount1,BatchNumber1,Product1,Quantity1,PO1,DateRequested1,DateDelivered1,Status1,Serial1,Voucher1,DateExpiry1
>   KeyAccount2,BatchNumber2,Product2,Quantity2,PO2,DateRequested2,DateDelivered2,Status2,Serial2,Voucher2,DateExpiry2
>   KeyAccount3,BatchNumber3,Product3,Quantity3,PO3,DateRequested3,DateDelivered3,Status3,Serial3,Voucher3,DateExpiry3

Next, the relevant PHP code for parsing CSV file.

```
<?php

// Start with anything else you need here

$inputfile = '/tmp/data.csv';

// Check to make sure the file exists and is readable
if (file_exists($inputfile) && is_readable($inputfile))
{
  // Read the whole contents of the file into an array instead of using fgetcsv
  $data = file($inputfile);

  // Remove the first line of data, optionally save it into $header
  $header = array_shift ($data);

  // Parse the rest of the data
  foreach ($data as $record)
  {
    // Optional, trim spaces on each sides
    $record = trim($record);

    // Skip empty lines
    if ($record == '') { continue; }

    // Separate the records by comma using explode
    // WARNING: May not give proper result if the record column contains comma character
    list ($KeyAccount, $BatchNumber, $Product, $Quantity,
          $PO, $DateRequested, $DateDelivered, $Status,
          $Serial, $Voucher, $DateExpiry)                 = explode(',', $record);

    echo "Record = $KeyAccount, $BatchNumber, $Product, $Quantity, $PO, $DateRequested, $DateDelivered, $Status, $Serial, $Voucher, $DateExpiry\n";

    // Do anything else you need here
    // $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO orders (KeyAccount,BatchNumber,Product,Quantity,PO,DateRequested,DateDelivered,Status,Serial,Voucher,DateExpiry) VALUES ('$KeyAccount','$BatchNumber','$Product','$Quantity','$PO','$DateRequested','$DateDelivered','$Status','$Serial','$Voucher','$DateExpiry')");
  }
}
```

Sample result:

```
$ php so.php
Record = KeyAccount1, BatchNumber1, Product1, Quantity1, PO1, DateRequested1, DateDelivered1, Status1, Serial1, Voucher1, DateExpiry1
Record = KeyAccount2, BatchNumber2, Product2, Quantity2, PO2, DateRequested2, DateDelivered2, Status2, Serial2, Voucher2, DateExpiry2
Record = KeyAccount3, BatchNumber3, Product3, Quantity3, PO3, DateRequested3, DateDelivered3, Status3, Serial3, Voucher3, DateExpiry3
```

Note that as mentioned in the code comment, we're not using [fgetcsv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read and parse the CSV file. Instead, we're using [file()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the whole file as array and then parse them one by one.

Not sure how the performance is between `fgetcsv()` vs `file()`. However, we're using similar code in one of our production server and it seems to work properly so far.

Comment: This would work fine as long as (a) no lines like `1,"a,b",2` and (b) the file is reasonably sized. If it is millions of records then this will likely run out of memory.

Comment: @manassehkatz Yes, that's why the condition above "The only catch is that the CSV data is simple comma separated values, ie: Comma is purely separator and not part of the column data". However, I missed the second catch that you added (reasonably sized), so thanks for adding that in.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this snippet to get the CSV data and unset the first row to remove the headers.

```
$csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
if (!empty($csv_data)) {
    unset($csv_data[0]); // skip the first row i.e the header
    foreach ($csv_data as $csv_row) {
        // do MySQL updation 
    }
}
```